# Update state when view loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First time working with React, I need to know how to update the state when the view loads.

All I am trying to do is a `GET` request in order to get a list of dealers for a Casino Game. Basically, I am missing 1 or 2 steps which are for render the dealers's list in the DOM

I will show what I am doing with my code and after that I will explain what I want

here is the first step in the actions part

**getDealerActions.js**

```
class GetDealersActions {

  constructor () {
    this.generateActions('dealerDataSuccess', 'dealerDataFail');
  }

  getDealers (data) {
    const that = this;
    that.dispatch();
    axios.get('someroute/get-dealers/get-dealers')
      .then(function success (response) {
        that.actions.dealerDataSuccess({...response.data});
      })
  }
};
```

then we move to the stores

**getDealersStore.js**

```
class GetDealersStore {

  constructor () {
    this.state = {
      dealerData : null,
    };
  }

  @bind(GetDealersActions.dealerDataSuccess)
  dealerDataSuccess (data) {
    this.setState({
      dealerData : data,
    });
   console.log(this.state.dealerData);
  }
}
```

in this case that `console.log(this.state.dealerData);` returns something like this which is exactly what I need

```
Object {dealersData: Array[3]}
```

the problems comes in the component part, honestly because I don't know how to handle the data there

```
    class Dealers extends Component {

      constructor (props) {
        super(props);
      }

      static getStores () {
        return [ GetDealersStore ];
      }

      static getPropsFromStores () {
        return GetDealersStore.getState();
      }

      render () {
       // here need to implement the .map function but
       // as this.props.dealerData is null, I am unable to render it.
        return (
          <div>
            <ActionButton onClick={this._getDealers}>Test</ActionButton>
           //in some part here I need to render the list of dealers
          </div>
        );
      }

      _getDealers = () => {
         console.log(this.props.dealerData);
         GetDealersActions.getDealers();
      }

    }
```

this `console.log(this.props.dealerData);` returns `null` the first time, I have to click twice on `_getDealers()` in order to get this

`{params: Object, query: Object, dealerData: Object}`

so, what should I do in the render method in order to get dealerData filled out? and what should I do to update the state once I am in the view ?

If you got it, all I need is to get `this.props.dealerData` with data and not `null`. So I can render it in this view.

Comment: You're logging `this.props` in `__getDealers`, but setting `this.state` in your handler. Is there an intermediary component that's missing from this?

Comment: @jkinkead nope, there is nothing missing actually. I already set the props to what I want with `componentWillMount () {GetDealersActions.getDealers();}` but when the view loads, first dealerData comes in null and then change to dealerData: data which is ok, but as first comes null, then the render method fires an error.

Comment: So, you shouldn't be setting a component's props manually - that will result in errors. You should only be setting state. However, it seems like your error is probably due to the fact that you're making an asynchronous call - your data probably hasn't returned by the time `render()` is first called.

Comment: @jkinkead can you give me a brief code sample ? please. I am struggling with this since yesterday

Answer (score 0):

The way this should be structured is:

```
class Dealers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    GetDealersActions.getDealers();
  }
  render() {
    let content;
    if (this.state.dealerData) {
      content = this.state.dealerData.map((datum) => {
        return <div>TODO: JSX!</div>;
      );
    } else {
      content = <div>Loading . . .</div>;
    }
    return <div>{content}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: The [React tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) covers almost exactly this type of code - it fetches a list of comments from a remote server.

Comment: there is an error here because actually `this.state` comes null

Comment: You can set an initial state in your constructor (`this.state = {};`).

Comment: and in which moment that state will take `dealerData` ? with this solution you gave, the view is always `Loading . . .`

Comment: Are you binding the handler in `GetDealersStore` to the correct `this`? I assumed you were, based on the original problem description (you said you'd eventually have the correct data show up). If `this` in `dealerDataSuccess` is bound to the instance of `GetDealersStore`, this will never work - you need to make sure it's bound to the instance of your component.

Comment: all the code I am implementing for this, is the code I pasted in the question

Comment: other thing I want to avoid that I just realized, is, that I don't to play with the state like this `this.state.dealerData.map` I rather with props, `this.props.dealerData.map`